# how to access a sub class object property if just give the super class object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a super class as ChartModel, and sub classes from ChartModel, in which there is a model called LineChartModel, and has a property `categoryType`.

now I have a method accept one parameter as (DataModel *) like:

```
- (void) showChartWithModel:(ChartModel *)dataModel {
    if ([dataModel respondsToSelector:@selector(categoryType)]) {
        if ([dataModel categoryType] == CategoryTypeDate) { // compiler error

        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler complains about [dataModel categoryType], because `categoryType` is not defined in `ChartModel`. I *DO NOT* want put `categoryType` into `super class`, because not every chart has such property. How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast `dataModel` to `id`:

```
- (void) showChartWithModel:(ChartModel *)dataModel {
    if ([dataModel respondsToSelector:@selector(categoryType)]) {
        if ([(id)dataModel categoryType] == CategoryTypeDate) { // compiler error

        }
    }
}
```

Or you could cast it to `LineChartModel`, in which case that's what I'd test for:

```
- (void) showChartWithModel:(ChartModel *)dataModel {
    if ([dataModel isKindOfClass:[LineChartModel class]]) {
        if ([(LineChartModel *)dataModel categoryType] == CategoryTypeDate) { // compiler error

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: second one is not a good idea, because I still has other chart model, like pie chart model. first one seems good!